# How to add a filter that shows tasks with a date range that includes today

Tags: notion

I'm trying to show Notion tasks that have a date range that spans 2 two dates and today falls in that range. But for some reason the date field when you add a filter about tasks that are for today, tasks with a date range, don't show.

Any ideas really welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to accomplish with an advanced filter. For example, if your range is one week previous to and one week past [today]...

1. Set filter on [Date property] for "Past - 1 - week"
2. Click three-dot menu in upper right of filter dialog
3. Click "Add to advanced filter"
4. Click "Add filter rule"
5. Set criteria as "Or - [Date property] - End date - Is relative to today - Next - 1 - week"

Another option that comes to mind is creating a formula property to return a boolean by which you can filter for true. A quick example:

```
prop("date") >= now().dateAdd(-7, "days") or (prop("date") <= now().dateAdd(7, "days") and prop("date")>= now())
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood your use case at all, though.

Comment: I'm not sure we need the dateAdd stuff. I think this is roughly it, but this formula doesn't evaluate correctly when It looks like it should: `dateStart(prop("Due Date")) >= now() and dateEnd(prop("Due Date")) <= now()`

Comment: I think I'm still trying to better understand the date range you're working with. The formula you provide will always return boolean false (an empty checkbox) as [Due Date].dateEnd() can't possibly be before now() if [Due Date].dateStart() is after now(). 

Does the filter suggestion provided above get closer than the formula to meeting your need?